# Natural connection on U(1) principal bundles over S^2 with Chern number>1

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

S^3 can be seen as a U(1)-bundle over S^2 (Hopf fibration).
It has first Chern number 1 or -1. 
Denoting with z_1,z_2 coordinates on C^2 and restricting to S^3
the natural connection form is
\omega_1=\bar z_1 dz_1+\bar z_2 dz_2

Consider now the U(1) bundles over S^2 with  Chern number n>1. They have total space S^3/Z_n where the Z_n action on C^2 is generated by (z_1,z_2)->(z_1\exp(i2\pi/n),z_2\exp(i2\pi/n)).
I know that the appropriate connection form which generalises the one of the Hopf bundle is
\omega_n=n(\bar z_1 dz_1+\bar z_2 dz_2)
I do not understand where the factor of n comes from. In other terms how do I see, from the defining properties of a connection form (or otherwise), that a factor of n is needed and/or that any other factor would give a one-form which is not a connection form?

Answer (score 1):

If you work out how the circle group acts on the fibres then the connection  form has to pull-back to the Maurer-Cartan form on the circle group. That will fix the multiple.